# Turning hybrid VueJS <script> tag to <script setup> (VueJS)

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs

**What I'm trying to achieve**

I'm trying to convert the content of `<script>` tags into `<script setup>` tags. I have been searching for a solution for a few hours now.

Both my original script and my hybrid script work, but trying to use nothing but the content of my `<script setup>` tags result in a bug that allows dragging-and-dropping, but then returns the dropped content to its original position.

**Technologies used:**

- VueJS 3/Inertia
- Laravel
- vuedraggable 4.1.0 package

**These are my template tags**

```
<template>
    <div class="flex m-10">
      <draggable class="dragArea list-group w-full" :list="list" @change="log">
            <div
                class="list-group-item bg-gray-300 m-1 p-3 rounded-md text-center"
                v-for="element in list"
                :key="element.name"
            >
                {{ element.name }}
            </div>
      </draggable>
    </div>
</template>
```

**This is the content of my original `<script>` tags  (works fine)**

```
<script>
    // The draggable is built with https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggable-next
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
    import { VueDraggableNext } from 'vue-draggable-next'
    export default defineComponent({
        components: {
            draggable: VueDraggableNext,
        },
        data() {
            return {
                enabled: true,
                list: [
                    { name: 'John', id: 1 },
                    { name: 'Joao', id: 2 },
                    { name: 'Jean', id: 3 },
                    { name: 'Gerard', id: 4 },
                ],
                dragging: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            log(event) {
                console.log(event)
            },
        },
    })
</script>
```

**This is my hybrid attempt at converting the content of my `<script>` tags into `<script setup>` tags (works fine)**

```
<script>
    // The draggable is built with https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggable-next
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

    export default defineComponent({
        data() {
            return {
                enabled: true,
                list: [
                    { name: 'John', id: 1 },
                    { name: 'Joao', id: 2 },
                    { name: 'Jean', id: 3 },
                    { name: 'Gerard', id: 4 },
                ],
                dragging: false,
            }
        },
    })
</script>

<script setup>
    // The draggable is built with https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggable-next
    import { VueDraggableNext } from 'vue-draggable-next';

    const draggable = VueDraggableNext;

    // let dragging = false;

    // const list = [
    //     { name: 'John', id: 1 },
    //     { name: 'Joao', id: 2 },
    //     { name: 'Jean', id: 3 },
    //     { name: 'Gerard', id: 4 },
    // ];

    // const enabled = true;

    const log = (event) => {
        console.log(event)
    }
</script>
```

**Attempt at a conversion to just `<script setup>` (works, but with a bug returning dropped content to its original position)**

```
<script setup>
    // The draggable is built with https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-draggable-next
    import { VueDraggableNext } from 'vue-draggable-next';

    const draggable = VueDraggableNext;

    let dragging = false;

    const list = [
        { name: 'John', id: 1 },
        { name: 'Joao', id: 2 },
        { name: 'Jean', id: 3 },
        { name: 'Gerard', id: 4 },
    ];

    const enabled = true;

    const log = (event) => {
        console.log(event)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: use vue3 reactive for objects and ref for scalars plus read docs how to use draggable with vue3